# Read GoLang Command Line Argument After Enter is pressed from shell script

Tags: shell, go, glide-golang

So I am using a OSS written in `go` which I don't have any exposure to. I am trying to automate that script.

SO this is how the script works
`calling_go_code`
Message for confirmation of user
Get user input
execute the code.

I am trying to automate this script.

So far this is what I have tried,
`sh test.sh Param1`

When I am running the script like

```
echo "hello"
calling_go_code
```

The above code asks for some parameter as input
test.sh

`sh test.sh Param1`

```
echo "hello"
calling_go_code -- $1
```

Comment: Is `expect` what you are looking for? https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @RichardHuxton's post. This is the solution I am using

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


set alias [lindex $argv 1]

set input [lindex $argv 0]

set timeout -1

COMMAND I AM USING 

expect {

    "*CONFIRMATION MESSAGE 1" { send -- $alias\r }


    exp_continue

}


expect {

    "*CONFIRMATION MESSAGE 2" { send -- $alias\r }


    exp_continue

}

expect eof
```

Calling bot

```
 ./bot param1 param2
```

Dependency of [Expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)